# Using a method of a .dll

Tags: c++, dll

could someone help me in this code?

I want to use a method that I declared in my .Dll ... I can use two of these methods, however one of them is giving me a lot of headaches ...
Follow the code below:

main.h -> DLL

```
 #ifndef _DLLTEST_H_
 #define _DLLTEST_H_

 #include <iostream>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <windows.h>

 extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void NumberList();
 extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void LetterList();
 extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int sumNumber(int, int);


 #endif
```

main.cpp -> DLL

```
 #include "main.h"

 #define MAXMODULE 50

using namespace std;

 char module[MAXMODULE];


 extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

 void NumberList() {

       GetModuleFileName(NULL, (LPTSTR)module, MAXMODULE);

       cout << "\n\nThis function was called from "
            << module
            << endl << endl;

       cout << "NumberList(): ";


       for(int i=0;  i<10; i++) {

            cout << i << " ";
       }

       cout << endl << endl;

 }



 extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

 void LetterList() {

       GetModuleFileName(NULL, (LPTSTR)module, MAXMODULE);

       cout << "\n\nThis function was called from "
            << module
            << endl << endl;

       cout << "LetterList(): ";


       for(int i=0;  i<26; i++) {

            cout << char(97 + i) << " ";
       }

       cout << endl << endl;
 }


extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

int sumNumber(int i, int j) {


    cout << "Number: " << i + j << endl;

    return i+j;
}
```

Testing my .DLL

```
#define MAXMODULE 50

using namespace std;

 typedef void (WINAPI*cfunc)();

 cfunc NumberList;
 cfunc LetterList;
 cfunc sumNumber;

 int main() {

       HINSTANCE hLib=LoadLibrary("libCriandoDLL.dll");


       if(hLib==NULL) {

            cout << "Unable to load library!" << endl;
            getch();
       }

       char mod[MAXMODULE];

       GetModuleFileName((HMODULE)hLib, (LPTSTR)mod, MAXMODULE);
       cout << "Library loaded: " << mod << endl;


       NumberList=(cfunc)GetProcAddress((HMODULE)hLib, "NumberList");
       LetterList=(cfunc)GetProcAddress((HMODULE)hLib, "LetterList");
       sumNumber=(cfunc)GetProcAddress((HMODULE)hLib, "sumNumber");

       if((NumberList==NULL) || (LetterList==NULL) || (sumNumber==NULL)) {

            cout << "Unable to load function(s)." << endl;
            FreeLibrary((HMODULE)hLib);
       }


       NumberList();
       LetterList();
       sumNumber(1,1);

       FreeLibrary((HMODULE)hLib);

       getch();
 }
```

The methods "NumberList ();" and "LetterList ();" work perfectly ... However, when I try to use the method "sumNumber (1.1)," he gives the following error:
"error: too many arguments to function"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring the imported functions all as taking no parameters and giving no return values:

```
 typedef void (WINAPI*cfunc)();

 cfunc NumberList;
 cfunc LetterList;
 cfunc sumNumber;
```

Declare `sumNumber` to correctly be of type `int (WINAPI*)(int,int)` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Actually, they should not even be declared as `WINAPI`, because they are not declared as such in the DLL.

Comment: `WINAPI` is just defined as `__stdcall` in `WinDef.h` - it's just a convenient shorthand for telling the compiler it needs to use C-style calling convention - correctly for a DLL, it is implied by the `extern "C"` at the other end.

Comment: Note that `__stdcall` is not `__cdecl`, which C and C++ functions use by default. Do you have a reference for `extern "C"` implying `__stdcall`?

Comment: @Angew: if you don't spell a calling convention, the default from project settings will be used, good way to shoot yourself in the leg. Good interface headers shall be explicit in that (and other configurable things like structure packing, etc)

Comment: @Angew I might actually be wrong on that part, it's a bit rusty here hehe - in my answer I was assuming he did match them up. As long as OP knows he needs to match them on both sides...  ;)